# Django makemigrations error on many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models, orm, m2m, dbm

What i want:

Store information about running of group of people.

What i did:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import timedelta


class Route(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Run(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    runners = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='RunnerResult', through_fields=["user", "run"])


class RunnerResult(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    run = models.ForeignKey('Run', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    result = models.DurationField(default=timedelta())
```

Problem:

When i do `makemigrations` i have the following error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
run.Run.runners: (fields.E339) 'RunnerResult.run' is not a foreign key to 'User'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'User': user?
run.Run.runners: (fields.E339) 'RunnerResult.user' is not a foreign key to 'Run'.
        HINT: Did you mean one of the following foreign keys to 'Run': run?
```

Tried to swap through_fields and models between each other and some other actions. I'm starting to think of my misunderstanding of M2M relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the `through_fields` in the *wrong order*. You first should specify the relation that refers to the *source*, and then then one to the *target*, so:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    runners = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through='RunnerResult',
        through_fields=('run', 'user')
    )
```

Since there is however only one `ForeignKey` to `Run`, and one to `User`, you do not need to specify the [**`through_fields=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields). So you can implement this as:

```
class Run(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    type = models.ForeignKey(Route, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    runners = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through='RunnerResult'
        # no through_fields
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: That helped for "makemigrations". But after migrate i have following problem:

ValueError: Cannot alter field run.Run.runners into run.Run.runners - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)

Will try ti fix this now.

Comment: @Naur: did you already migrate to a `ManyToManyField` *without* a `through=...`? Because adding a `through=...` is not really something Django migrates properly with. I think in that case you better remove the m2m, migrate, and then create a new one with a `through`.

Comment: I've done as you said, migrated without M2M, and then returned this code and migrated again, everything works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Willem Van Onsem, I tried this, and performing two migrations one after another resulted without errors. But some data related to the models were lost in this process. May be the best way here is to write a custom migration instead of relying on automatic migrations mechanism ?